# Split ML model in 2 models

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

Having a very simple general **trained** ML model, I would like to be able to **split it into 2 other models** having the following structure:

InitialModel has N layers with M neurons each. InitialModel can be treated as a linear regression or classification task, so the output will be a single value.

As a concrete example, I can treat my InitialModel as follows:

```
class SimpleAgeRegrNet3D(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SimpleAgeRegrNet3D, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
            # 64
            nn.Conv3d(1, 6, kernel_size=3), 
            nn.MaxPool3d(2),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # 31
            nn.Conv3d(6, 16, kernel_size=3), 
            nn.MaxPool3d(2),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # 14
            nn.Conv3d(16, 120, kernel_size=3),
            nn.MaxPool3d(2),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # 6
            nn.Conv3d(120, 84, kernel_size=3),
            nn.MaxPool3d(2),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # 2
            nn.Conv3d(84, 1, kernel_size=2),
        )
        
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.encoder(x)
```

> MyInput -> InitialModel -> Output (shape=(1,))

After transformation:

> MyInput -> Model1 (output shape = (M,)) -> (input shape= (M,))Model2 -> Output (shape=(1,))

Ideally, if my **trained** InitialModel has N layers, I would like to create Model1 which has the first N * 3/4 layers (for example) and Model2 which has the rest of the layers of the initial model. In the end, I would like to be able to reconstruct them so if I have Model1 and **Person2** has Model2, I can send the output of Model1 to **Person2** and then he will do the final inference.

Comment: We will need more info to be able to help you. Why do you want the split? what should be the output of model1? Which library are you using? Any example code would also be great. Otherwise, I doubt you will get a helpful answer because it is hard to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have added some more explanations.

Comment: By looking at the code, I am assuming you are using PyTorch. Try to add that technology as a keyword, since I will help experts locate your question. Some people will just filter questions by PyTorch. Also, if someone gives you a helpful comment or answer, do not forget to upvote them to encourage other people answering you.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I am new and this really helped me.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please **re-read** [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and notice that questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for SO.

Comment: I changed the question. However, if I dont have an idea of how to solve my problem, I am wondering how to ask or where since I would like some help. Thanks!